# How can i make my app when running it to start clean on every launch?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my onCreate in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        serverChecksThread.start();
        status1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        uploadedfilescount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberofuploadedFiles);
        uploadedfilescount.setText("Uploaded Files: 0");

        addListenerOnButton();
        initTTS();
    }
```

initTTS is for using text to speech.

```
public void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }
```

The problem is that when i'm running over and over again the application through android-studio the app start clean/reseted. But when i'm running the application over and over again on my android device in this case lg g3 i click on the app icon so each time it remember the last action sometimes it's just a TextView text that changed or sometimes the text to speech so sometimes i see the changed text and sometimes i hear the last voice speeched. Like it's remembering the last actions.

I tried an hour ago to add this to my MainActivitiy.java

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainScree.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    }
```

But MainScreen not exist so i'm not sure what should i add instead of it.
And also i'm not sure if this is the right way to do it at all.

Comment: I don't think you really want to clean start the app - that is not really the "Android way". Look at the "Android Activity Life Cycle" and you should be able to clear your state the way you want based on the events that occur when the OS pauses/hides you app.

Comment: Why are you starting a new activtiy in onResume, if you want to start MainScree then you should declare it as a launcher activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are suggesting is not user friendly nor the "android way" 
when pressing the home button  the App moves from Resumed(visible) to paused(partially visible) until android needs the memory/resources for another app then moves to Stopped and destroyed .

we can always use

```
 @Override
    public void onPuase() {
        finish();
    }
```

but this will cause you a lot of problems in the app flow later on .
[image: Android Activity life cycle]

editted :: to achive the data cleaning without missing with flow

Add this to your manifest file to the actvity that you want to be cleared every time : 
`android:noHistory="true"`
 
and override your on back press :

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { super.onBackPressed(); finish(); }
```

Comment: Sarah then what should i do to make that when i click the app icon on my device each time the app will start clean ? I mean will start over again and not like now that some actions left behind like speech or texts. If clicking the back button or the home button and then click the app icon to run it again then i want it to start clean. Not when clicking the back/home buttons but when clicking on the app icon to run it again then to make it start clean without any trace.

Comment: I added it to the Answer please check it :)